# Join and group the elements of a list into a string according to certain conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have a list of objects that look like this:

```
[
    { "id": 1, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200, ... },
    { "id": 2, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200, ... },
    { "id": 3, "ifsG0": "1-G02", "price": 140, ... },
    { "id": 4, "ifsG0": "1-G03", "price": 90, ... },
    { "id": 5, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200, ... },
    { "id": 6, "ifsG0": "1-G03", "price": 90, ... },
    { "id": 7, "ifsG0": "1-G02", "price": 140, ... },
    { "id": 8, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200, ... },
    { "id": 9, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200, ... },
    { "id": 10, "ifsG0": "1-G03", "price": 90, ... },
    { "id": 11, "ifsG0": "1-G03", "price": 90, ... },
    { "id": 12, "ifsG0": "1-G02", "price": 140, ... },
]
```

And I would like to get a string like this:

```
"ifsG0#quantity#price#ifsG0#quantity#price#ifsG0#quantity#price..."

result = "1-G01#5#200#1-G02#3#140#1-G03#4#90"
```

I have done some research and am getting there with this solution, but I can't find it clean at all. Would there be a way to do it all in one line.

*PS: the prices will always be the same for all identical `ifsG0s`.*

```js
var list = [
    { "id": 1, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 },
    { "id": 2, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 },
    { "id": 3, "ifsG0": "1-G02", "price": 140 },
    { "id": 4, "ifsG0": "1-G03", "price": 90 },
    { "id": 5, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 },
    { "id": 6, "ifsG0": "1-G03", "price": 90 },
    { "id": 7, "ifsG0": "1-G02", "price": 140 },
    { "id": 8, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 },
    { "id": 9, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 },
    { "id": 10, "ifsG0": "1-G03", "price": 90 },
    { "id": 11, "ifsG0": "1-G03", "price": 90 },
    { "id": 12, "ifsG0": "1-G02", "price": 140 },
];

const sortedList = list.sort((a,b) => (a.ifsG0 > b.ifsG0) ? 1 : ((b.ifsG0 > a.ifsG0) ? -1 : 0));
var partNoCounts = sortedList.map(gi => gi.ifsG0).reduce((a, c) => (a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + 1, a), Object.create(null));
var partNo = Object.keys(partNoCounts).map(g0 => g0 + '#' + partNoCounts[g0] + '#' + sortedList.find(gi => gi.ifsG0 === g0).price).join('#');

console.log(partNo);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `reduce` and `flatmap`

```js
var list = [
    { "id": 1, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 },
    { "id": 2, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 },
    { "id": 3, "ifsG0": "1-G02", "price": 140 },
    { "id": 4, "ifsG0": "1-G03", "price": 90 },
    { "id": 5, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 },
    { "id": 6, "ifsG0": "1-G03", "price": 90 },
    { "id": 7, "ifsG0": "1-G02", "price": 140 },
    { "id": 8, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 },
    { "id": 9, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 },
    { "id": 10, "ifsG0": "1-G03", "price": 90 },
    { "id": 11, "ifsG0": "1-G03", "price": 90 },
    { "id": 12, "ifsG0": "1-G02", "price": 140 },
];

var ifs = list.reduce((a, l) => {
  if (!a[l.ifsG0]) a[l.ifsG0] = { p: l.price, q: 0 }
  a[l.ifsG0].q++
  return a
}, {})

var partNo = Object.keys(ifs).sort().flatMap(i => [i, ifs[i].q, ifs[i].p]).join('#')

console.log(partNo);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just a 'group by' mapped to a string. Doing it in one line isn't necessarily better, but you can simplify it to a single `reduce()`, move the `sort()` call to after the to make it more efficient, and then `flatMap()` and `join()` the sorted array.

```js
const
  list = [{ "id": 2, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 }, { "id": 1, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 }, { "id": 3, "ifsG0": "1-G02", "price": 140 }, { "id": 4, "ifsG0": "1-G03", "price": 90 }, { "id": 5, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 }, { "id": 6, "ifsG0": "1-G03", "price": 90 }, { "id": 7, "ifsG0": "1-G02", "price": 140 }, { "id": 8, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 }, { "id": 9, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 }, { "id": 10, "ifsG0": "1-G03", "price": 90 }, { "id": 11, "ifsG0": "1-G03", "price": 90 }, { "id": 12, "ifsG0": "1-G02", "price": 140 },],

  partNo = Object
    .values(
      list.reduce((a, { ifsG0, price }) => (
        (a[ifsG0] ??= { ifsG0, price, count: 0, }).count += 1, a), {})
    )
    .sort((a, b) => a.ifsG0.localeCompare(b.ifsG0))
    .flatMap(({ ifsG0, count, price }) => [ifsG0, count, price])
    .join('#');

console.log(partNo);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce`and `Map` Object to get the quantity. Then use a simple sort and map to get the result.

```js
const list = [
  { id: 11, ifsG0: "1-G03", price: 90 },
  { id: 1, ifsG0: "1-G01", price: 200 },
  { id: 2, ifsG0: "1-G01", price: 200 },
  { id: 3, ifsG0: "1-G02", price: 140 },
  { id: 4, ifsG0: "1-G03", price: 90 },
  { id: 5, ifsG0: "1-G01", price: 200 },
  { id: 6, ifsG0: "1-G03", price: 90 },
  { id: 7, ifsG0: "1-G02", price: 140 },
  { id: 8, ifsG0: "1-G01", price: 200 },
  { id: 9, ifsG0: "1-G01", price: 200 },
  { id: 10, ifsG0: "1-G03", price: 90 },
  { id: 12, ifsG0: "1-G02", price: 140 },
];

const output = [ ...list.reduce( (acc, e) =>
      acc.set(e.ifsG0, { ...e, qty: (acc.get(e.ifsG0)?.qty || 0) + 1 }),
    new Map()
    )]
  .sort()
  .map(s => `${s[1].ifsG0}#${s[1].qty}#${s[1].price}`)
  .join("#");

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `reduce` that tracks the quantity and `map`s into the desired result.

```
const partNo = Object.values(list.reduce((b, a) => {
   if (b.hasOwnProperty(a.ifsG0)) b[a.ifsG0].quantity++;
   else b[a.ifsG0] = {...a, quantity: 1};
   return b; }, {}))
  .sort((a,b)=>a.ifsG0.localeCompare(b.ifsG0))
  .map(e => [e.ifsG0, e.quantity, e.price].join('#')).join('#')
```

```js
var list = [{ "id": 1, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 },
    { "id": 2, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 },
    { "id": 3, "ifsG0": "1-G02", "price": 140 },
    { "id": 4, "ifsG0": "1-G03", "price": 90 },
    { "id": 5, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 },
    { "id": 6, "ifsG0": "1-G03", "price": 90 },
    { "id": 7, "ifsG0": "1-G02", "price": 140 },
    { "id": 8, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 },
    { "id": 9, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 },
    { "id": 10, "ifsG0": "1-G03", "price": 90 },
    { "id": 11, "ifsG0": "1-G03", "price": 90 },
    { "id": 12, "ifsG0": "1-G02", "price": 140 }];

const partNo = Object.values(list.reduce((b,a)=>{ if (b.hasOwnProperty(a.ifsG0)) b[a.ifsG0].quantity++; else b[a.ifsG0] = {...a, quantity: 1}; return b; },{}))
  .sort((a,b)=>a.ifsG0.localeCompare(b.ifsG0))
  .map(e=>[e.ifsG0, e.quantity, e.price].join('#')).join('#')

console.log(partNo);
console.log("1-G01#5#200#1-G02#3#140#1-G03#4#90 -- desired")
```

Comment: Not sorted by `ifsG0` names

Comment: @User863 - not sure what you mean. It's sorted and matches the desired output.

Comment: it's 'sorted' because the input is in order.

Comment: Thanks peeps. Updated with a localeCompare sort

Answer (score 1):

One more way to do this, using Array.reduce again and some destructuring, optional chaining (?.), then Array.flat() and Array.join(), and Object.values:

```js
const list = [
    { "id": 1, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 },
    { "id": 2, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 },
    { "id": 3, "ifsG0": "1-G02", "price": 140 },
    { "id": 4, "ifsG0": "1-G03", "price": 90 },
    { "id": 5, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 },
    { "id": 6, "ifsG0": "1-G03", "price": 90 },
    { "id": 7, "ifsG0": "1-G02", "price": 140 },
    { "id": 8, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 },
    { "id": 9, "ifsG0": "1-G01", "price": 200 },
    { "id": 10, "ifsG0": "1-G03", "price": 90 },
    { "id": 11, "ifsG0": "1-G03", "price": 90 },
    { "id": 12, "ifsG0": "1-G02", "price": 140 },
];

const result = Object.values(list.reduce((acc, { ifsG0, price } ) => { 
    return { ...acc, [ifsG0]: [ifsG0, ((acc?.[ifsG0]?.[1]) || 0) + 1 , price ]};
}, {})).flat().join("#")

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You forgot the sorting for ```ifsG0```. The input can be not in order.